# Add member to bound list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am practicing data binding in WPF.

I have Song.cs file with Song Class. Values don't change, so there is no point of adding INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
class Song
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    private string artist;
    public string Artist 
    {
        get { return artist; }
        set { artist = value; }
    }

    private string album;
    public string Album
    {
        get { return album; }
        set { album = value; }
    }

    public static Song Load(string record)
    {
        var split = record.Split(';');
        Song song = new Song();
        song.Artist = split[0];
        song.Album = split[1];
        song.Title = split[2];
        return song;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} / {1} / {2}", artist, album, title);
    }
}
```

Then I have SongList.cs which contains method to load some initial songs and this class derives from ObservableColection.

```
class SongList : ObservableCollection<Song>
{
    public static SongList Load()
    {
        SongList result = new SongList();

        Song s1 = Song.Load("The Offspring;The Americana;Staring At The Sun");
        result.Add(s1);

        Song s2 = Song.Load("Metallica;Reload;Unforgiven II");
        result.Add(s2);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The data is bound to Listbox in XAML

```
 <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

And then in MainWindow Constructor I am setting datacontext to load list of songs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SongList songs = SongList.Load();
    Song newSong = Song.Load("AC/DC;Back In Black;Hells Bells");
    songs.Add(newSong);
    listBox.DataContext = songs;
}
```

And here is my question. I want to add Song to my SongList everytime I click the button, but I have no idea how to acces this list from my ButtonClick event handler.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're practicing with WPF, I think you should start implementing your applications, applying the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). You can find some useful resources in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish).

Anyway, to keep things simple you should have something like this:

```
public class MainWindow
{
SongsList songs;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    songs = new SongList();
    listBox.DataContext = songs;
}

public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    songs = SongList.Load();
    Song newSong = Song.Load("AC/DC;Back In Black;Hells Bells");
    songs.Add(newSong);
    listbox.Items.Refresh();
}

}
```

Applying the MVVM pattern, creating a related `ViewModel` for your application and exposing the songs list as property of `ViewModel` bound to the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListBox`, you won't need to invoke `listbox.Items.Refresh();` because you will implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

When you say
`Song newSong = Song.Load("AC/DC;Back In Black;Hells Bells");`

You are making `newSong` a local variable. You need to have it as a class level member variable to make it accessible. So declare it outside `MainWindow` then modify it in `Button_Click`.

I hope you have kept both of them in the code behind of the same XAML File.

Comment: When I create an instance of my list outside constructor method MainWindow() then the list is accessible inside the Button1_Click event handler.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I meant, sorry for putting it in fancy words. You need to declare `SongList songs` outside `Main`. Please go through some articles on Scopes and access modifiers if you are not familiar already.